# How to know when dd has finished

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop, embedded-linux, dd

I have a issue with the dd comand. I use it in a while like this:

```
while c=$(dd count=1000 bs=1 2>/dev/null) ;do

    echo -n "$c" > /dev/ttyO5
done < $FILE
```

And it works like charm, the only problem is that once the file is read completely, it doesnt stop the while, it stays there stalled. How could I make the while to stop once the dd read all the file?

BTW: Note my machine is embed linux, it doesnt have all the comands and tools as a normal ubuntu machine would have.

Thanks

Output `dd --version`

```
BusyBox v1.20.2 (MUSE) multi-call binary.

Usage: dd [if=FILE] [of=FILE] [bs=N] [count=N] [skip=N]
        [seek=N]

Copy a file with converting and formatting

        if=FILE         Read from FILE instead of stdin
        of=FILE         Write to FILE instead of stdout
        bs=N            Read and write N bytes at a time
        count=N         Copy only N input blocks
        skip=N          Skip N input blocks
        seek=N          Skip N output blocks

Numbers may be suffixed by c (x1), w (x2), b (x512), kD (x1000), k (x1024),
MD (x1000000), M (x1048576), GD (x1000000000) or G (x1073741824)
```

Comment: Can you output `dd --version`?

Comment: Done, i edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note

- '\0' will be lost after assigning to a variable.
- '\\' may keep its special meaning depending on version of echo : try `echo '\n'`

Status can be retrieved reading from stderr

```
dd count=1000 bs=1 </dev/null
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
```

So

```
while
    c=$(dd ... 2>errorfile); 
    read line <errorfile;   # read the first line of error
    [[ $line != 0+0* ]];    # break while if line begins with 0+0
do
    ...
done
```

It's slightly different from checking from length of c

```
c=$(dd count=1 bs=1 </dev/null)
echo "${#c}"


c=$(dd count=1 bs=1 <<<$'\0')
echo "${#c}"
```

because in the last case a NUL character was read whereas in the previous no character were read.

EDIT: following demonstrates that it works but is very slow :

```
for x in {{0..9},{a..f}}{{0..9},{a..f}}; do printf "\x$x"; done |
while
    c=$(dd count=1 bs=1 2>errfile;echo .); c=${c%.}
    read line <errfile
    [[ $line != 0+0* ]]
do
    if [[ $c = '' ]]; then printf "\0"; else echo -n -E "$c"; fi
done | od -c
```

Comment: What if i would writte the file straight with dd? would i loose `null` and  `\n`?

Comment: if file contains NUL characters (possible if binary) you can retrieve them only with count=1, and in this case c will be empty [[ $c = "" ]]

Comment: because shell variables cannot contain NUL character: `str=$(printf "hello\0world"); echo "$str" | od -c`

Comment: Ok, i noticed that, empty var `c`. What about `\n` ?

Comment: in some version of echo you need to add `-E` option, on the line `echo -n "$c" ...`

Comment: I meant, If i write the file lik just `dd if=$InFILE of=$OpFile count=.....` does it keep the `null` and `\n` like this?

Comment: no, when you use if=$infile, option the file is open each time it enters in the loop so reads the same byte, the while redirection the position is kept

Comment: the only problem which remains is that `c=$(printf "\n")` and `c=$(printf "\0")` gives empty string, so this construct can't distinguish NUL and newline charc

Comment: the solution can be to append a character and remove it after: `c=$(dd ...; echo "."); c=${c%.}`

Comment: Could you move this to chat? i dont have enough reputation yet.

Comment: i don't know how to do that

Comment: Well, there´s literally no way i can do this with the tools i have. The only and last option i have is to read everything in hexadecimal, then change the `null` and `\n` for something else and transfer. Not even with appen option you told me it works.

Comment: in fact it works but it's very slow, updated with alltogether

Comment: ok, it works on local machine. But the problem is that i wanna keep the data in binary to transfer it to the other machine and read it again and store in file. This code would transform my data

Comment: OMG, doesn't `dd` set an error code? Can't you call `stat` and check file size beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `if` and `of`, why not use them,

test.sh:

```
dd if=$1 of=/dev/ttyO5 count=1000 bs=1 2>/dev/null
```

output:

```
root@localhost~# ./test.sh file.txt
The quick brown fox jumps over the bashy dog.
root@localhost~#
```

Comment: Sorry, I try to send and receive data over a serial cable, so i need to try to send byte per byte otherwise i might loose some data on the way, that's why i put it on a while.

Comment: You were sending 1000 bytes at a time, not one. **Nahuel** has the appropriate answer.